# How to get all the text relative to an element SPAN Style With JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, styles

Hi I'm new programming in Javascript.
And it looks very interesting.

I'm getting elements from a webpage using Javascript.

Speccially I want to get the outerHTML text of a SPAN Element with Id Style and certain Value: "display:inline-block;width:270px;"

So This is an example:

"DESIRED_TEXT"

THE DESIRED TEXT Is that I wanna get.

And Im interested to get it with this rules, because in source code there are a lot of different kinds of SPAN Elements.

Then add many items as many find are found on source code on a Javascript Array.

I Have a method, but this is just for get ElementsBy Name:

```
"function GetNames()
  { 
    var images = document.getElementsByName('ListaFolios');
   var srcList = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].getAttribute('value'));
    };"
    return srcList.join()
  }"
```

Thats a part of HTML Code to parse:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:270px;">3CA6CE9B-B23F-49BC-B54B-3F4DFC894C51</span></td><td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">BBA830831LJ2</span></td>
<td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:250px;">BBVA BANCOMER, S.A.</span></td><td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">MCE0708241W5</span></td><td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:250px;">MG7 CONSTRUCCION Y EDIFICACION SA DE CV</span></td>
<td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">2015-01-01T03:58:02</span></td><td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">2015-01-01T04:31:14</span></td>
<td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">BBA830831LJ2</span></td>
<td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">$938.44</span></td>
<td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">Ingreso</span></td><td style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;"><span style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">Vigente</span>
```

Now the goal is to differentiate  150px because are two values identical with:

```
span style="display:inline-block;width:250px
```

and `span style="display:inline-block;width:150px`

For The `span style="display:inline-block;width:270px` I have no problem, I suppose that the web owner decided to put a unique value because Its a Unique Record.

### **FOR THE 150PX.**

I Joint the values resultant in an Array. And Looks something like this:

```
* Fecha de Emisión,CTU020225385 ,MCE0708241W5 ,2011-07-01T13:22:53,2011-07-01T13:23:01,TLE011122SC2 ,$6,100.00,Ingreso,Vigente,,CCO8605231N4 ,MCE0708241W5 ,2011-07-01T17:08:25,2011-07-01T17:08:26,DIA031002LZ2 ,$200.00,Ingreso,Vigente,,OEX950605MJ6 ,MCE0708241W5 ,2011-07-02T08:44:20,2011-07-02T08:44:20,DIA031002LZ2 ,$200.00,Ingreso,Vigente,,SAGC471229QB3,MCE0708241W5 ,2011-07-02T13:08:00,2011-07-02T13:08:01,SFE0807172W8 ,$2,360.12,Ingreso,Vigente,,CTU020225385 ,MCE0708241W5 ,2011-07-04T13:11:33,2011-07-04T13:12:06,TLE011122SC2 ,$12,200.00,Ingreso,Vigente,,CCO8605231N4 ,MCE0708241W5 ,2011-07-04T17:37:30,2011-07-04T17:37:30,DIA031002LZ2 ,
```

I'm Looking that theres a pattern between CTU020225385,CCO8605231N4,OEX950605MJ6 and SAGC471229QB3.  Between these values are 7 items.

So I need to delete this 7 items on array and so on, for only get these values following these pattern.

Regards

Comment: Instead of getting elements by some "styles" assign to your elements ID or CLASS and go with that normal selectors.

Comment: Also I tried with QuerySelector, but instead of get the desired text I get this: [object HTMLSpanElement].      And thats my code:   var nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[style=""display:inline-block;width:270px;""]'));
  window.status = nodesArray.join();

Comment: OK, cool, but have you seen the below answers?

Comment: @GerardoGarcía Too many quotation marks at `'[style=""display:inline-block;width:270‌​px;""]'` , try `'[style="display:inline-block;width:270‌​px;"]'`

Comment: Hi Roko C. Buljan. I know that is a good Idea, but the issue is that is not my website. So I can't control the source code.

Comment: @GerardoGarcía Can include example of `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
  var st = spans[i].style;
  if(st.display.match("inline-block") && st.width.match("270px")) {
      // We have a match! Do something with that element
      alert( spans[i].innerHTML ); // "DESIRED_TEXT"
  }
}
```

Comment: I add an example of HTML in Question:

Comment: First As the First I don't want the first item, I deleted:srcList.splice(0, 1);   So I can continue to after one item delete 7 items and so on.